# How to group mixins in Dart?

Tags: dart, mixins

I have a base package that defines A:

```dart
class A {}
```

Then a package that defines this:

```dart
mixin Aa on A {}
mixin Ab on A {}
abstract class First extends A with Aa, Ab{}
```

and another that defines this:

```dart
mixin Ax on A {}
mixin Ay on A {}
abstract class Last extends A with Ax, Ay {}
```

Then the package that gets that together with the problem

```dart
abstract class Clazz extends A with First, Last {} // <- Can't have those mixins bc they don't extend from Object
```

**Question**: Is there a way of grouping mixins or are we forced to implement them one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forced to implement the one-by-one.

There is currently no way to combine mixins into units that can be applied as one.
Hopefully there will eventually be something like that. It's one the language team's radar (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/540), but so is a lot of other enhancements.