# How to write some arbitrary initialization code in a Dart mixin?

Tags: dart, oop, mixins

Say I have a package that exposes a `mixin` that provides some extensibility through an API:

```dart
mixin ListenerModifier<T> {
  T get value;
  void addListener(Callback callback);
  void removeListener(Callback callback);
}
```

Say I want to make a "plugin" based on this mixin:

```dart
mixin PreviousValue<T> on ListenerModifier<T> {
  late T previous;

  const PreviousValue() {
    addListener(() => previous = value);
  }
}
```

(You could also have plugins defined in other packages as well, perhaps to expose a `Stream<T>` getter.)

Then, a user could use any plugins at will, like this:

```dart
abstract class MyListener<T> with ListenerModifier<T>, PreviousValue<T> {}
```

The issue is, mixins can't have constructors like the above `PreviousValue` assumes. Is there some OOP/architectural way to get around this problem? I initially thought of just forcing users of `PreviousValue` (for example) to call a `registerPreviousValue()` method in their `MyListener` constructor as a workaround, but that is highly error prone.

Related:

- [How to group mixins in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248686/how-to-group-mixins-in-dart)
- [How can I initialize a mixin's immutable data in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54166892/how-can-i-initialize-a-mixins-immutable-data-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

Just realized for the particular example I gave, I can use a different sort of plugin system without mixins:

```dart
mixin ListenerModifierPluginAPI {
  T get value;
  void addListener(Callback callback);
  void removeListener(Callback callback);
}

abstract class ListenerModifier with ListenerModifierPluginAPI {
  T registerPlugin<T>(T Function(ListenerModifierPluginAPI) plugin) => plugin(this);
}

class MyListenerModifier extends ListenerModifier {
  late final PreviousValueState previousValueState;

  const MyListenerModifier() {
    previousValueState = registerPlugin(previousValuePlugin);
  }

  // ...
}
```

This may not work for all people though. If someone has a different solution, I am all ears.